# How to show loading icon till await finishes

Tags: javascript, async-await, loading

I have a async function with await fetch.
I want to show a loading icon to user till the await completes and then show the next div.

```
                let getOTP = await fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "text/plain"     
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        "Number": mobileNumber
                    })
                });

                let data = await getOTP.json();
                let errorCode = data.errorCode;
                if (errorCode == 0) {// show next div}
```

I have tried used setTimeout(function (){},5000) functions set to 5 seconds (or more) but sometimes it takes longer for the reply to come. So, How do I show a loading icon till the await completes ?

Comment: you should to received a event from backend to stop the charge

Comment: Where do you put the setTimeout call? show it in context with the other code, please

Answer (score 11):

Simply display loader before fetch, and remove it after `await`.

```js
const fetchButton = document.querySelector('#fetchButton')
const loader = document.querySelector('#loader')
const content = document.querySelector('#content')

function fetchData() {
  // Here should be your api call, I`m using setTimeout here just for async example
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'my content'))
}

fetchButton.onclick = async function () {
  content.innerHTML = ''

  // Your loader styling, mine is just text that I display and hide
  loader.style.display = 'block'
  const nextContent = await fetchData()
  loader.style.display = 'none'

  content.innerHTML = nextContent
}
```

```html
<button id="fetchButton">Fetch</button>
<div id="loader" style="display: none">Loading...</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: You should use try-finally to make sure the loading icon is also hidden when something goes wrong with the loading

Comment: @NineBerry Absolutely, if you are using real fetch api or axios that can throw it is mandatory to handle errors. But in my example `setTimeout` won't throw for sure :) Nonetheless, `finally` case isn't necessary if error is handled inside `fetchData` function and it won't affect loading toggle functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Start the loading image in the beginning of your code and stop it when there is no error and your code enter in the `(errorCode == 0)` condition.

```
            <-- START loading Here -->
            let getOTP = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "text/plain"     
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "Number": mobileNumber
                })
            });

            let data = await getOTP.json();
            let errorCode = data.errorCode;
            if (errorCode == 0) {
               <-- STOP loading Here -->
            }else{
               <-- STOP loading Here on error -->
            }
```

Comment: Why would you not want to hide the loading icon if the loading fails?

Comment: I have added the code but this is not the right way to down vote. You can put a comment only. You can see that, the complete code is not provided by the OP, so we can not imaging what should be the steps followed in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the code to hide the icon after the line that calls `await`. Use `try` / `finally` to make sure that the code is also executed when something goes wrong in your asynchronous call.

You can encapsulate this mechanism in a function like the `WithIcon` function as shown below to reuse it at different places.

```js
// Test function
async function test()
{
    await WithIcon(timeout(3000));
    testAfterAction();
}

function testAfterAction()
{
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.innerText = "Some text";
    document.body.appendChild(elem); 
}

// Use setTimeout to symulate some asynchronous i/o operation
function timeout(ms) 
{
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}


// While awaiting the promise, show a wait icon
async function WithIcon(promise)
{
    ShowAwaiting();
    try
    {
        await promise;
    }
    finally
    {
        HideAwaiting();
    }
}

// To only hide the icon when every ShowAwaiting call was met with a HideAwaiting call
var globalAwaitingCounter = 0;

// Show wait icon
function ShowAwaiting()
{
    if(globalAwaitingCounter <= 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("awaiting").style.display = "inline";
        globalAwaitingCounter = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        globalAwaitingCounter++;
    }
}

// Hide wait icon
function HideAwaiting()
{
    if(globalAwaitingCounter <= 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("awaiting").style.display = "none";
        globalAwaitingCounter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        globalAwaitingCounter--;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="test();">Test</button>
  <span id="awaiting" style="display:none">Awaiting....</span>
</body>
</html>
```